# How can I filter multiple numbers using Advanced Filter option?

Tags: microsoft-excel, advanced-format

Please help me understand how do I filter multiple numbers using Advanced Filter option?

Filtering text works for me, but not the numbers. Is there any format required?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should have a header for the advanced filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's missing is column label/headers/title which Advanced Filter seems to be using (see the popup in the beginning of the screen recording) to associate the columns to match (which in a one column filter it would really not be needed, it seems to still need it.)

[image]